# Difference between catalog_product_prepare_save and catalog_product_save_before

Tags: event-observer, catalog, programmatically, save

What is the difference between `catalog_product_prepare_save` and `catalog_product_save_before`?

I have an observer that updates some attributes when a product is saved. It works great when I save a product from admin, however it doesn't work when saving from a script I wrote.

Through my research in writing the observer, I was using `catalog_product_save_before`. Someone on here told me I should be using `catalog_product_prepare_save`. Although it didn't solve the problem at the time, I kept with it as eventually I got everything working.

My new research is telling me when I call `$product->save()`, it doesn't trigger `catalog_product_prepare_save`, but it does trigger `catalog_product_save_before`, so I'm considering switching my observer to `catalog_product_save_before` but can't find much documentation between the two. Wondering if I'm going to experience any adverse behavior by switching since I'm not sure why several people told me to use `catalog_product_prepare_save` in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`catalog_product_save_before` is one of standard events called by the `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` class in its `_beforeSave()` method. The line looks like this:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before', $this->_getEventData());
```

For every model that extends `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` a set of standard events are run which other modules may hook into without the need to write them manually in your class. They are, among others:

- `{$prefix}_save_before`
- `{$prefix}_save_after`
- `{$prefix}_delete_before`
- `{$prefix}_delete_after`
- `${prefix}_save_commit_after`
- `${prefix}_delete_commit_after`

.. etc. Prefix is taken from protected property `_eventPrefix` which by default is set to `core_abstract`. You should only set that in any of your classes to make those standard events specific to your model.

On the other hand `catalog_product_prepare_save` is a custom event called only in 2 places in magento: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Api` and `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController` so you can use them to hook into product update done via admin panel or API but not any other means.

Comment: Thank you. So is there any issue with using save_before instead of prepare_save?

Comment: No, it is not. You need to only be aware it will be used anytime any part of the code uses `save()` method on `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` class. On the other hand it does not guarantee you that you will catch all instances when product data are changed. Some module may directly call `$product->getResource()->save($product)` which will skip those default events from model layer. And there is function `saveAttribute()` in `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract` (and `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product` extends it) which directly updates attribute related table.